# How can I run a macro that takes the names of the workbook?

Tags: excel, vba

I want to run a macro in which I specify the name of the workbook I want to use.

The name of the workbook changes like `Data (1), Data (2), Data (3) …` because I might open the same file more than 1 time.  The same happens for the workbook Salary, sometimes it appears as `Salary (1), Salary (2)…` and is giving me an error of ”Subscript out of range”.

How can I run a macro that takes the name of the workbook

> Data, Data (1), Data (2) … and Salary, Salary (1), Salary (2)…

```
For i = 1 to 100

If Workbooks(“Data”).Worksheets(“Shee1).Cells(i,4).Value = 100 Then
.
.
.

For i = 1 to 100

If Workbooks(“Salary). ”).Worksheets(“Shee1).Cells(i,4).Value < 2000 Then
.
.
.
```

Comment: Just use something like `Activesheet.name` or `Sheets(1).Name`. Or am I not understanding something in your question?

Comment: If you want to run macro always in active workbook, use `ActiveWorkbook` instead of `Workbook("Data")`.

Comment: @BruceWayne I run the macro from a  different workbook and I have those 2 workbooks, so I cant use activesheet.  I need to specify from which workbook because the calculations are different for each of them

Comment: @EganWolf I run the macro from a  different workbook and I have those 2 workbooks, so I cant use activesheet.  I need to specify from which workbook because the calculations are different for each of them

Answer (score 3):

Iterate through the workbooks collection:

```
Dim wb       As Excel.Workbook
Dim wbSalary As Excel.Workbook
Dim wbData   As Excel.Workbook

For Each wb In Workbooks
    If wb.Name Like "Data*" Then
        Set wbData = wb
    Else If wb.Name Like "Salary*" Then
        Set wbSalary = wb
    End If
Next

'// For example...
MsgBox wbData.Name & " contains " & wbData.Sheets.Count & " worksheets."
MsgBox wbSalary.Name & " contains " & wbSalary.Sheets.Count & " worksheets."
```

Then use `wbData` and `wbSalary` in your code to refer to that workbook

Answer (score 2):

This Code will work with all opened workbooks that its name start with `Data` or `Salary`:

```
Sub Test()

 Dim Wb As Workbook
 Dim i As Long

 For Each Wb In Workbooks

   If Wb.Name Like "Data*" Then
        For i = 1 To 100
          If Wb.Worksheets("Shee1").Cells(i, 4).Value = 100 Then
            '....
            '....
          End If
        Next

    ElseIf Wb.Name Like "Salary*" Then
        For i = 1 To 100
          If Wb.Worksheets("Shee1").Cells(i, 4).Value < 2000 Then
            '....
            '....
          End If
        Next
    End If

 Next
End Sub
```

if you want to work with all opened workbooks that its name contain `Data` or `Salary` then change `"Data*"` and `"Salary*"` to `"*Data*"` and `"*Salary*"`.

Comment: just curious why you provided an *identical* answer to one that was already given (except that you placed the OP's pseudo-code inside the `IF block`?

Comment: @ScottHoltzman, the other answer only work with one workbook (the last one that loop find it). but it will not work with all workbooks as in this question: `Data (1), Data (2), Data (3)` and `Salary (1), Salary (2)…`. my answer will work with all these workbooks.

Comment: I see what you mean now. As written @Macro Man's code will set the workbook first, but not process it inside the `If` block. OP would have to put his code after the `Set` statements to process.

Comment: @ScottHoltzman, You are right , both answers are the same if we put `MsgBox wbData.Name.....` inside the loop in the other answer.

Comment: If you look at my edit revisions - I did actually use this logic in my first post, but reading the question again I think the OP has just re-opened another temp version of the same workbook as opposed to having multiple workbooks open - of course it would help if the OP actually gave feedback on the answers to let us know! Either way +1 because great minds obviously think alike :)

Comment: @MacroMan, thank you, and i'm sorry about posting very very similar answer to your answer, but i saw the OP add 2 comments to the question and didn't gave feedback on the answer or accept it, so i understand from this that the answer not work as he want, and I understand things in this way even on my own comments and answers. [like this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/34313757/4039286), when I didn't saw any feedback on my first comment I thought it didn't work and spent a lot of time to post another way in new answer.

Comment: @Fadi no need to say sorry haha it might *look* similar but it does a different thing and the most important thing is that people learn something. That's what we're all here for!